# Using terraform and sysprep/unattend to provision windows vm

Tags: terraform, vsphere, sysprep

I'm trying to deploy virtual machines in `vsphere` using `terraform` and running into issues with `sysprep/unattend` files.  I am supplying an `unattend.xml` file using

```
customize {
  windows_sysprep_text = "${file("${path.module}/unattend2012.xml")}"
}
```

but the terraform apply times out after 10 minutes with...

```
==>timeout waiting for customization to complete
```

The virtual machine is sitting at a "**Choose your keyboard layout**" screen.

Comment: After the VM is created, does it reboot during customization?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this opened (and closed issue): https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/355 I would suggest ensuring you have all the variables configured. If you think you have them all, you might want to update your question with the sanitized inputs.